# How to display more than 1 terminal simultaneously

Tags: gnome-terminal, console

Sometimes when I work, I use more than one terminal and I find it inconvenient to switch between them when all of them were invoked using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Is there any program or terminal that after launching would provide me with 4 independent terminals each of them would occupy ¼ of the screen while making it easy to switch between them, for instance by using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key?

Comment: The `[TAB]` key is already used for auto completition in the terminal. If you were to swich the instances by e.g. `[ALT]+[TAB]`, it really would be easier to use positioned windows instead as suggested by @Zacharee1 .

Comment: If you're _very_ serious about this, check out some _tiling window managers_ such as [Xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) or [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/).

Comment: I would have to open multiple terminals and resize it everytime I start working. It would kill one of the best advantage of Linux: customizability.

Comment: try guake or yakuake

Comment: use `uxterm` as terminal emulator (`sudo apt-get install xterm`), it’s the Unix standard, and you can invoke it multiple times and arrange them on the display as you see fit

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You need *Terminator*:

```
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

[image: Terminator 4 windows]

For four terminals at start-up, do the following:

- Start terminator
- Split the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- Split the upper terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- Split the lower terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
- Open *Preferences* and select *Layouts*
- Click <kbd>Add</kbd> and enter a usefull layout name and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Close *Preferences* and *Terminator*
- Open *Terminator* with this command:

  ```
  terminator --maximise --layout=<your_layout_name>
  ```

  or with this command:

  ```
  terminator --maximise --borderless --layout=<your_layout_name>
  ```

---

Jump between the terminal windows with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

You can assign *your personal* terminator command to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Keyboard Settings > Shortcuts. (Thx [@Wilf](https://askubuntu.com/users/178596/wilf))

Of course you can also create a `terminator.desktop` file. Copy the original desktop file and make your changes:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
nano ~/.local/share/applications/terminator.desktop
```

Comment: Note you can also assign the `terminator ...` command to Ctrl+Alt+T in Keyboard Settings > Shortcuts

Comment: Is there any way to set which terminal window is active after start ?? When I launch it active window is at the bottom and I would like active terminal window to be at the top but I cant handle it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't recommend Terminator these days. As cool as it used to be, the project is now pretty much unmaintained, and uses an ancient (~4 years old) version of VTE (which is the widget doing the actual terminal emulation). That is, while it's cool to have many windows next to each other, what's happening inside each window will suffer from many issues. See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/1030562

Comment: @egmont https://code.launchpad.net/~gnome-terminator/terminator/gtk3

Comment: @A.B. yes I know, that branch contains my work :) While it uses the most recent and much better VTE, the UI around it (Terminator itself) is heavily work-in-progress with quite a few bugs that are not present in the default Gtk+-2 version.

Your answer with the `apt-get install terminator` command clearly refers to the Gtk+-2 version that uses ancient VTE. For reference it's indeed useful to mention the Gtk+-3 version which is not yet stable and not yet shipped by Ubuntu, but someone might try out.

Comment: @egmont That you could write in the answer as a supplement. =)

Comment: You need _Terminator_. Epic.

Comment: @maryisdead I should write "You need a Terminator" ;)

Comment: worked and very useful :)

Comment: Where can we see a list of all terminator shortcuts? UPDATE: found it! **Right click --> Preferences --> Keybindings tab.**

Comment: Note that the "preferences" menu is accessed by right-clicking on the screen, and **Ctrl + Shift + E** splits vertically, or you can just select it from the right-click menu.

Comment: `terminator` with a 2x2 view (4 terminals at once open in the same window) works GREAT for running ROS (the Robot Operating System), since ROS requires so many stinking terminals open to simultaneously run multiple processes!

Answer (score 18):

You can start 4 Terminals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and fit them to the edges of your screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad[1,3,7,9]</kbd> or left/right with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad[4/6]</kbd> or top/bottom <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad[8/2]</kbd> and switch with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to ONE Terminal and with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key above Tab</kbd> between the terminals if one is active.

Or

You can use tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and switch between the terminals with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Page-Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page-Down</kbd>.

Comment: Under which desktop environment does the Ctrl+Shift+Numpad work?

Comment: I've a standard Ubuntu installation with Unity

Comment: It's Ctrl+Alt+Numpad

Answer (score 12):

As another alternative, I would suggest using [`byobu`](https://byobu.org/).

> Byobu is a GPLv3 open source text-based window manager and terminal multiplexer. It was originally designed to provide elegant enhancements to the otherwise functional, plain, practical GNU Screen, for the Ubuntu server distribution. Byobu now includes an enhanced profiles, convenient keybindings, configuration utilities, and toggle-able system status notifications for both the GNU Screen window manager and the more modern Tmux terminal multiplexer, and works on most Linux, BSD, and Mac distributions.

The advantage is that it is text-based, meaning you can use it *without* a graphical environment! This is very useful when dealing with servers, which often don't have a GUI.

You even have a bottom status bar with a lot of useful information, like the date/time, the load average, etc.

The shortcuts you have to know if you use Byobu are:

- <kbd>F2</kbd> creates a new tab.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> creates a new split tab (this splits your current tab horizontally).
- <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> to switch between tabs.
- <kbd>F9</kbd> to configure Byobu.

`sudo apt-get install byobu` will install Byobu.

As a bonus, being a terminal multiplexer, it means you won't lose your session and your tabs if you closed the terminal by mistake. And you can run `byobu` in another terminal and get synchronised outputs.

There are even scripts to save the layouts if you wish to persist the session across reboots.

Comment: byobu domain url changed to https://byobu.org/

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I use `emacs` with `M-x ansi-term` or `M-x shell` depending on what I am doing.

But if you are looking for *just* a terminal multiplexer then there is always the quietly revered `tmux`:

https://github.com/tmux/tmux

Edit: JoKeR pointed out that you can install `tmux` with `apt-get`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tmux
```

Comment: you can install tmux with: `sudo apt-get install tmux` you should mention that I guess.

Comment: Never used `tmux` myself, just know about it.  Thanks for the clarification though I'll put it up top.

Answer (score 6):

You can use *tmux*, a terminal multiplexer.

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

For four panels you can use this script `4pSession`, create the script with

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
touch ~/bin/4pSession
chmod +x ~/bin/4pSession
nano ~/bin/4pSession
```

and add the code below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# if the session is already running, just attach to it.
tmux has-session -t 4panel
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  sleep 1
  tmux attach -t 4panel
else 
  tmux new-session -d -s 4panel
  tmux split-window -v
  tmux split-window -h
  tmux select-pane -t 0
  tmux split-window -h
  tmux select-pane -t 0
  tmux -2 attach-session -d
fi
```

Than you can create a desktop file:

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/tmux.desktop
```

with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=tmux
Comment=a terminal multiplexer
Exec=/<path_to_script>/4pSession
Icon=terminal
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Terminal;
```

Move between the panes with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and than <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just resize your terminal windows, so they all fit a corner of the screen. The Terminal can also have tabs, which might help out. Right click the window and select `New Tab`.

Here's how to make windows able to resize to corners:

1. Run `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.
2. Run `sudo ccsm` or search `ccsm` in Unity Dash.
3. Scroll down until you find `Grid`, under `Window Management`. Make sure it is enabled.
4. Go to the `Corners / Edges` tab and change the `Corner` options to their corresponding corners.

Comment: Then I am not able to look at all tabs in the same time and I have to resize it everytime I open terminal.

Comment: @Bundy there is a way to make it so windows resize to a quarter of the screen when dragged to a corner. Let me find it, and I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My crude contribution to this question: install `wmctrl` and adjust the script bellow,that opens and positions four terminal windows, to your screen. 
First  find out the size of your screen with `xwininfo -root` and then adjust `-e` parameters (they are in this order 0,x-position,y-position,width,height). Numbers I use bellow are just example

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: 2/18/2015
# Description: Open 4 terminals and position them






gnome-terminal -t WINDOW-ONE &
gnome-terminal -t WINDOW-TWO &
gnome-terminal -t WINDOW-THREE &
gnome-terminal -t WINDOW-FOUR &

sleep 0.5
wmctrl -r WINDOW-ONE -e 0,0,0,500,250 &
sleep 0.5
wmctrl -r WINDOW-TWO -e 0,0,384,500,250 &
sleep 0.5
wmctrl -r WINDOW-THREE -e 0,500,0,500,250 &
sleep 0.5
wmctrl -r WINDOW-FOUR -e 0,500,384,500,250 &
```

You could bind this as a shortcut, for instance to Ctrl+I or whatever. Another idea, without installing wmctrl, is to open 4 `--geometry=` option

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend tmux. It offers a whole lot of customizations and total independence from the mouse (if that is concern). You can split screens horizontally, vertically, switch between them with some keystrokes, leave sessions open and reconnect to them later, etc.

Comment: Please explain, how to do that (see [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer)).

Comment: 1. If you are using centos, you can head over to 
[link](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/tmux/)
to grab the latest rpm and install it. If you get errors about dependencies, I came across an excellent tutorial here:
[link](http://elroyjetson.org/dev-notes/centos/installing-tmux-on-centos-6-2)

2. If you are on Ubuntu, it is simple:
sudo apt-get install tmux

3. If you are comfortable compiling packages, then there is the source code on sourceforge:
[link](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer, if you want to add information.

Answer (score 0):

With 4 terminal windows open, and while working in one of them, I can simply switch among them with Alt+` (left tick) if want to use keyboard, or simply click on the launcher icon of the terminal to bring up all its windows and click on the chosen one.

[image]

My installation is Ubuntu 14.04, with the default (Unity 3D) desktop, and updated to-date.

I don't get it why people complicate things and install 3rd party products when the default Ubuntu installation already provides the feature.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Gnu Screen for this also, and use a vertical split, and horizontal split.

you can put these in your `~/.screenrc` config file.  I have been able to split using most any gnu screen, with proper adjustments to .screenrc file.

Some combo of below should do you in your `.screenrc`.

```
screen -t tl 1 bash
split 
focus down
screen -t bl 3 bash
split -v
focus down
screen -t br 4 bash
select 1
split -v
focus down
screen -t tr 2 bash
```

I had it set for 6 screen once. heres my residual config from that

```
 30 ## 1 a local bash
 31 # screen -t host03 1 bash
 32 #sessinoname blamb1
 33
 34 ## 2 ssh to host04
 35 # split -v
 36 # focus
 37 # select 2
 38 # resize -6
 39 # screen -t host04 2 ssh host04
 40 # caption string "%{kk}XXXXXXX"
 41
 42 ## 3 bashed
 43 # focus
 44 # select 1
 45 # split
 46 # focus
 47 # select 3
 48 # screen -t bashed 3  bash
 49 #exec ssh host04
 50 # caption string "%{kk}XXXXXXX"
 51
 52 ## 4 bashedup
 53 # split
 54 # focus down
 55 # screen -t bashedup 4 bash
 56 # caption string "%{kk}XXXXXXX"
 57
 58 ## 5 compass
 59 # split
 60 # focus down
 61 # resize -14
 62 # screen -t compass 5 bash
 63 # leave caption commented till resize works
 64 #caption string "%{kk}XXXXXXX"
 65
 66 #focus up
 67
 68
 69 ## 5mysql
 70 # exec mysql -p
 71 # screen -t mysql 5 mysql
 72
 73 ## 6php
 74 # screen -t php.ini 6 vim /etc/php/php.ini
 75 # select php.ini
 76 # chdir /etc/php
 77 # exec vim php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the application "screen"

Install screen by running the following command:

```
apt-get install screen
```

To verify that screen has been installed, run

```
screen -v
```

within a screen session, you can create a new window by pressing CTRL + A, then C. Your old window will remain active and you can perform other tasks. To switch between windows, press CTRL + A, then N (for the next window) or CTRL + A, then P

Answer (score 0):

There are inbuilt shortcuts for this, and easy navigation too.

`Ctrl + Alt + T`    - press once to start the 1st terminal
`Ctrl + Shift + T`  - press 3 times, to get 3 more terminal as Tabs, within the same window of 1st terminal
`Alt + 1` or `Alt + 2` or `Alt + 3` or `Alt + 4` - each will these will switch to corresponding tab/terminal.

Hope that helps.