# Getting gnome-terminal to run tmux on start

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, zsh, tmux

I'm trying to figure out how to get my gnome-terminal to launch run `tmux -2` on starting. I have tried modifying the `Exec` lines in the `gnome-terminal.desktop` file to `Exec=gnome-terminal -e -tmux -2` and to `Exec="gnome-terminal -e -tmux -2"` But I am having no luck. I have also tried similar things within my `.zshrc` file, but nothing seems to work, all that ever happens is a new gnome-terminal window running zsh will open.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: that could be interesting for you: http://askubuntu.com/a/616341/367165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `gnome-terminal.desktop` file, you need the Exec to contain the command exactly as you would run it via a shell.  In this case, the `gnome-terminal` executable `e` parameter needs a quoted string to execute:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'tmux -2'
```

Comment: For those curious, if you wanted the Gnome Terminal to attach to an existing Tmux session if it exists, change the command to `gnome-terminal -e 'tmux attach'` and add this to your .tmux.conf as a new line `new-session -n $HOST`