# How to open multiple VIEWABLE tabs in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, xterm

How can I How to open multiple *viewable* tabs in the Ubuntu terminal?

Not by opening a new one, but similar to that used in XTerm.

Comment: What does that mean? Include a screenshot or something. And it's *GNOME Terminal*, not *Ubuntu Terminal*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display more than 1 terminal simultaneously](http://askubuntu.com/questions/612131/how-to-display-more-than-1-terminal-simultaneously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install terminator, and you can do exactly what you are trying to.

Answer (score 2):

You can open multiple instances of `gnome-terminal` that will show up as independent windows you may align next to each other.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> always opens a new window, as well as launching it from the Dash (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) or HUD (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).